# Apache flume fetches wrong data

Tags: twitter, flume

I am using apache flume 1.3.0 and I gave some keywords in the keyword field of flume file to search for data in twitter. As usual, flume brings data in json format but it also fetches some data which does not contain the keywords which i mentioned.

Comment: Can you add the keywords here? Also one example of wrong tweet?

Comment: @RamananR...my keywords are microsoft,oracle,google,yahoo,wipro,ibm,dell,intel,accenture,infosys

Comment: Also a tweet which doesn't contain these words?
Or your code snippet?

Comment: @RamananR....my wrong tweet is "text":"RT carlosfilocahua: ccobaep El contenido fenoménico de las experiencias https://t.co/8ASrB1E6HN http://t.co/mY04DMQFR8"